# Что представляет собой тип System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator<T1,T2>?

Tags: c#, linq

Изучая LINQ наткнулся на то, что результат запроса имеет такой тип, но информации по нему найти не удалось.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,cffd4efbf86815cb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Информации не удалось найти из-за [закона Деметры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B).

> объект должен иметь как можно меньше представления о структуре и свойствах чего угодно

Класс `WhereSelectArrayIterator` реализует *Декоратор* и *Адаптер* *Итератора*. *Декоратор*, *Адаптер* и *Итератор* — три паттерна, описанные в классической книге [GoF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).

Метод `Enumerable.Select` получает на вход *Итератор* (любой класс, реализующий интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>`) и возвращает другой *Итератор*. Новый *Итератор*  является *Адаптером* потому что преобразует интерфейс `IEnumerable<T1>` в интерфейс `IEnumerable<T2>`.

Для того, чтобы вызывать метод `Select` нам достаточно знать только, что на входе и выходе у нас `IEnumerable<T>`. По закону Деметры знать реальный тип возвращаемого объекта нам не нужно.

Если мы не знаем деталей реализации, то создатели LINQ вольны выбирать любую реализацию, и наш код продолжит работать корректно.

Как видим, создатели LINQ, очевидно, в целях минимизации кода, сделали один класс для выполнения двух разных операций: **Where** и **Select**. Так что здесь реализован не только паттерн *Адаптер*, но и паттерн *Декоратор*, который добавляет новое поведение, а именно фильтрацию. В целях оптимизации они сделали разные классы для коллекций тех типов, с которыми они умеют работать быстро в обход стандартного интерфейса, а именно, для списков и для массивов.

Таким образом, получились классы `WhereSelectArrayIterator<T1, T2>` и `WhereSelectListIterator<T1, T2>`. Каждый из них, в зависимости от параметров конструктора, выполняет фильтрацию и отображение входной последовательности `IEnumerable<T1>` в выходную последовательность `IEnumerable<T2>`. Первый предназначен для быстрой обработки массивов, а второй — списков. Это то, что мы можем предположить. При прочих равных условиях большего знать нам и не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Этот тип возвращается функцией `Select` при следующих вызовах если она применена к массиву:

```
arr.Select(...)
arr.Select(...).Select(...)
arr.Where(...).Select(...)
arr.Where(...).Select(...).Select(...)
arr.Where(...).Where(...).Select(...)
```

И так далее.

Вот прямо так и проверяют:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    // ...
    if (source is TSource[])
    {
        return new Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator<TSource, TResult>((TSource[])source, null, selector);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Смысл существования данного класса - оптимизация LINQ при работе с массивами. Данный класс реализует интерфейсы IEnumerable и IEnumerator.

Исходный код этого класса можно увидеть тут: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L418

Реализация `IEnumerator<TResult>` у этого класса тривиальная - просто хранится индекс текущего элемента в поле `index`, в методе `MoveNext` он увеличивается пока не дойдет до допустимого элемента или до конца массива.

Реализация `IEnumerable<TResult>` у этого класса сложнее и спрятана в базовом классе `Iterator<TResult>`. Там используется популярный трюк для уменьшения нагрузки на сборщик мусора: в методе `GetEnumerator()` делается проверка что объект создан в текущем потоке и что метод `GetEnumerator()` еще ни разу не вызывался; если это так то возвращается `this`, иначе возвращается новый объект.

Наконец, довольно важной частью являются методы `Select` и `Where`, которые используются для оптимизации построения цепочек из методов LINQ.

Метод `Select` возвращает новый `WhereSelectArrayIterator`, тем самым позволяя тянуть цепочку из вызовов `.Select()` сохраняя оптимальный доступ к массиву.

Метод `Where` не дает новых оптимизаций, но нужен потому что объявлен абстрактным в базовом классе. Он возвращает `WhereEnumerableIterator` который работает с произвольной последовательностью.